# Mingliu font not working on linux

Tags: java, linux, fonts, itext

I have linux machine with java installed on it . I have written a program that takes a html and makes a pdf out of using IText . this program is working on my local . I see the same program is not working on the server .
How do i resolve this. I assume that the font is not recognized on the linux machine.
Can some one tell me how to attach the font to the jvm.

Comment: You probably want to put a font file, often a .tcc suffixed one, into your personal .font directory or perhaps /usr/share/font.  Then run fc-cache -v and see if 1) the file is mentioned and 2) that the font now works.

Comment: I have the font in my class path and i am registering the font using in the code . Do it still need to do what i said .. Also how is the same code working on my windows machine

Comment: Maybe a  WinANSI font (should work) or the path is not correct when case-sensitive.

Comment: How about placing the font inside jdk will it work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue for this . While writing the PDF file to disk , the encoding of the file was not UTF-8 . When i fixed this , everything started working fine

Comment: Pdfs are binary files. If you write binaries using some character encoding like utf-8, you damage them. Thus, this answer as it appears here is wrong. Probably you did some funny forward and backward encoding and decoding which cancels out, and at some place you used utf-8. But even if it now works with such steps cancelling each other out, these steps are simply unnecessary.